# Dynamic Pivot SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to prepare a dynamic pivot in SSIS. I can create it in SQL Server itself without using pivot component of ssis. But how it can be exported to Excel Destination is my problem. The number of columns are dynamic.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A dataflow cannot have a dynamic number of columns.  The columns have to be defined at creation time, and cannot be modified at run-time.

You can look at BiMLScript to build your package dynamically based on the results of your dynamic pivot query.

You can also use BCP to export the results of the dynamic pivot to a .csv file and then just open the .csv with Excel.

If neither of those is satisfactory, the only other option I know is to do the entire export with a Script Task.

Comment: I would probably use PowerShell to export it to CSV or Excel, but I find using BCP to be rather unpleasant.

Comment: @BaconBits  well I find using BCP to be fun and rewarding.   So there.   ;-p

Comment: I just don't want to deal with creating a header row with BCP for a query with a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: I can create pivot dynamically but my requirement is how to create the excel destination dynamically

Comment: @sasi yes, I know, that is what my answer addresses.   Is there something in it you didn't understand?   To create the Excel destination dynamically, you can use BiMLScript to build the package based on the dynamic pivot.   There is no way to do it in simple SSIS.

Comment: Could you please suggest me the script sample for the below requirement. my data is 

====================
Project id     Year   Amount 
10               2016        50     
10               2017         60 
5                 2016         60          
===================
I want the Excel destination file as follows 

======================
Project_id      2016        2017 
10                    50            60 
5                      60 
=====================
Here my years are dynamic. sometimes it may be 3 or more.

Thanks

Comment: No I don't have a script handy for something like this.